# Link django model attributes between classes

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I have a django model with

```
class Comment():
   created = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='comment_created')
```

How do I set an attribute of the Comment class based on the user referenced by "created".

To be specific I would like the idiomatic way to reference (inside the comment instance) whether or not the user who created the comment "is_staff".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, creating method of Comment model class in this way may work:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    # some fields...

    def created_user_is_staff(self):
        return self.created.is_staff()
```

you can use this method in some.py

```
# comment is an instance of the Comment class
    if comment.created_user_is_staff():
# do something...
```

or in a template

```
{% if comment.created_user_is_staff %}
    render something...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Comment(models.Model):
  created = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='comment_created')

  @property
  def creator_is_staff(self):
    return self.created.is_staff

my_user = User.objects.get()  # Get some user
my_comment = Comment(created=my_user)
my_comment.creator_is_staff  # Returns either True or False
```